# Square Connect API List Locations and Inventory Adjust return 404 not found

Tags: c#, square-connect

I am able to get all the categories and all of the items with no problem. When I try to get a list of locations or adjust inventory I get an error message.

My code to get the locations:
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me/locations");
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

```
        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        string responseMessage = null;
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    responseMessage = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
```

My code to adjust the inventory is:
    Uri uri = new System.Uri(string.Format("https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me/inventory/{0}", variationId));
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "PUT";
            request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

```
        string postData = "{\"quantity_delta\":" + adjustAmount.ToString() + ",\"adjustment_type\":\"MANUAL_ADJUST\"}";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();
        dataStream.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close ();

        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        string responseMessage = null;
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    responseMessage = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
```

For both of the statements at the lines response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
 I get The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found

Any help is very much appreciated as I do not understand why part of my code is working but these two pieces are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An app needs to be created after 02/16/2016 to use the v1 locations endpoint, as indicated in the [Business Management Overview section](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#business-overview): "*The endpoints described in this section cannot be used by applications that were created before 16 February 2016. See [Connect API changes (2016-02-16)](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/connect-api-changes-2016-02/) for more information.*" Could you verify if the app was created after 02/16/2016? If not, could you please create a new app and give it a try?

For the 404 on inventory adjustment, could you please provide an item variation ID for further investigation?

Comment: Thanks for the help. It fixed the first problem as my application was to old. I created a new one and the locations call worked fine. I am still having the same issue with the inventory adjustment.  The variation ID I am testing with is 06659ab1-9323-4666-73a0-d7bd8c9d3320. The new uri is:
 Uri uri = new System.Uri(string.Format("https://connect.squareup.com/v1/{0}/inventory/{1}",_location_Id, variationId));

Comment: Could you try again with *POST* for your inventory adjustment request, instead of *PUT*?